# Can we say "the treatment does more good than harm"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

We often say

> [do more harm than good](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-more-harm-than-good): idiom: to be damaging rather than helpful:
>
> *Modernizing historic buildings often does more harm than good.*

Say, a person has a cancer and need a treatment which might make him lose weight or hair or a lot of good cells, but overall it can cure his cancer.

Can we say "**the treatment will do him more good than harm**"?

Comment: You can find [many examples in Google Books.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22more+good+than+harm%22)

Comment: You've used the "word-request" and "phrase-request" tags, but it's not clear what meaning you're requesting a word or phrase for. Can you either edit the question or fix the tags?

Comment: "more good than harm" is the expected state for a medical treatment, so it wouldn't need a special phrase.